# sonata_type_model_list - set default value?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

How can i set default value in Sonata Admin for sonata_type_model_list?

For text i can:

```
->add('title', 'text', array('required' => false, 'data' => 'default value'))
```

but i try:

```
->add('demo', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('data' => 1))
```

then i have error:

```
Class 1 does not exist
```

If i pass instead of 1 object Demo with id: 1 then i have error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   Alex\TempBundle\Entity\Demo, but is a(n) integer. You can avoid this
>   error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms a(n) integer to an instance of
>   Alex\TempBundle\Entity\Demo.

Comment: Are you doing it like `->add('demo', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('data' => $myDemo))` where `$myDemo` is an instance of `Demo`? Because error explicitly states, that you have passed an integer, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is to assign the object before calling the ->add(...) method.

You can fetch the object first:

```
// Load your associated object
$object = new DemoObject();
$formObject = $this->getSubject();
$formObject->setDemo($object);
```

Now the selected object should be the default value of the list.
In my case that works pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
->add('demo', 'sonata_type_model', array( 'data' => '1' ));
```